# how do i share/communication between each services from cloud run to gke

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, environment-variables, google-kubernetes-engine, load-balancing

3 service are running in cloud run and 3 service are running in gke cluster in same GCP Project

All 6 service should talk to each other. We have APIs that stored in .env.production variable through that it talk to each other all 6 services

Here is the example of one service i used in deploy gke cluster

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: xxxxx-api
 namespace: xxxxx
spec:
 replicas: 2
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: xxxxx-api
 template:
   metadata:
     labels:
       app: xxxxx-api
   spec:
     containers:
       - name: xxxxx-api
         image: xxxxxxxxx/xxxxx-api:2024-02-06-1310
         imagePullPolicy: Always
         ports:
         - containerPort: 8080
         env:
         - name: JAVA_OPTS
           value: "-Xms2g -Xmx2g"
         - name: "API_xxxxx"
           value: "https://xxxxx.xx.xxxxx.in" 
         - name: "TEST_xxxxx"
           value: "https://xxxxx.xx.xxxxx.in/api/test"
         - name: "TESTING_xxxxx"
           value: "https://xxxxx.xx.xxxxx.in/api/testing"
```

Same i create 2 more for other service with different KEY-VALUES in it

Now Question is How they can communicate with each other from cloud run to gke cluster and this build and deploy using github action

I have create 3 domain name for 3 cloud run services and they are connected to each other

How can i same applied to GKE do i need to create 3 domain name and added LB and add SSL to it after that i need to add in yaml file which above im sharing (will it work or not dont know)

Im confuse do i need to create 3 domain name and attach to global LB then ssl certificate

if not required do we have any other alternate option without creating 3 domain name, ssl and LB

Answer (score 1):

There are many options. But to keep it simple:

- Use [Google Cloud DNS](https://cloud.google.com/dns?hl=en) to set domain names for all your services. You will have to create a Private Zone and attach it to your VPC.
- For the apps on GKE to call Cloud Run. You can set the Cloud Run Services Ingress settings on [internal](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/ingress). This way your apps GKE will be able to either resolve the Cloud DNS FQDN (aka domain) or you can set Cloud DNS On top of that.
- For the cloud Run service to call GKE. You need to expose your GKE Services behind an Internal LoadBalancer (You can use an application LB or a TCP LB). Register those LB's to DNS and use [VPC Serverless Connector](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access) to access those internal loadbalancers from Cloud Run.